# Reading Buffer Data using C++ AMP

Tags: c++, directx, c++-amp

I can't seem to find a way to let myself read the data from my AMP array.

What I want to be able to do, is take my buffer, copy it into a vector and then use the vector. I'm aware that I should set the CPU access flags, but I'm having trouble doing so.

Firstly, this is how I'm trying to access the buffer. I'm putting this here first just in case I have done something how it shouldn't be done. Perhaps there is a function built in that I've missed that does this for me?

```
std::vector<Pticle> vecParticles;
    ID3D11Buffer* pBuffer = reinterpret_cast<ID3D11Buffer *>(concurrency::direct3d::get_buffer(m_arrParticles));
    D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE MappedResource;
    m_pDeviceContext->Map(pBuffer, 0, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, 0, &MappedResource);
    {
        auto pData = (Pticle*)MappedResource.pData;
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < m_uiNumParticles; ++i)
        {
            vecParticles.push_back(pData[i]);
        }
    }
    m_pDeviceContext->Unmap(pBuffer, 0);
```

Basically it should write all the data from the buffer into the vector

Now I know I should set my access flags, however I can't seem to do it. I write in the following function in my initialise:

```
m_Accelerator.set_default_cpu_access_type(concurrency::access_type::access_type_read_write);
```

however it breaks, with the following error

```
"Invalid access_type specified. accelerator does not support zero copy."
```

I'm not sure what this means, if I'm attempting to set it up to read and write, didn't it pass the test? It also does it on any access type I try.

How can I set it up so that I can read the data from the buffer?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a DX buffer and then use `make_array` to create a C++AMP `array`.

```
HRESULT hr = S_OK;
UINT bufferSize = 1024;
D3D11_BUFFER_DESC bufferDesc =
{
    bufferSize * sizeof(float),
    D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT,
    D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER | D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE |
        D3D11_BIND_UNORDERED_ACCESS,
    0 /* no CPU access */,
    D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_BUFFER_ALLOW_RAW_VIEWS /* misc flags */,
    sizeof(float)
};
D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA resourceData;

ZeroMemory(&resourceData, sizeof(D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA));
std::vector<float> vertices(bufferSize, 1.0f);
resourceData.pSysMem = &vertices[0];
CComPtr<ID3D11Buffer> buffer;
hr = device->CreateBuffer(&bufferDesc, &resourceData, &buffer);
assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));

array<float, 1> arr = make_array<float, 1>(extent<1>(bufferSize), dxView, buffer);
std::wcout << "Created array<float,1> on " 
    << arr.accelerator_view.accelerator.description << std::endl;
```

Note that the device and buffer must meet a set of requirements for this to work. The Direct3D device must implement the ID3D11Deviceinterface with feature level D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0 or above. C++ AMP accelerator_views can be accessed from multiple threads, so the  device should not be created with the D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_FLAG D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_SINGLETHREADED set.

The Direct3D buffer must implement the ID3D11Bufferinterface. It must support raw views (D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_BUFFER_ALLOW_RAW_VIEWS) and allow SHADER_RESOURCE and 
UNORDERED_ACCESSbinding. The buffer itself must be of the correct size, the size of the extent 
multiplied by the size of the buffer type.

You can create a C++ AMP `accelerator` using `create_accelerator_view` as shown here.

```
HRESULT hr = S_OK;
UINT createDeviceFlags = 0;
#ifdef _DEBUG
    createDeviceFlags |= D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG;
#endif
std::array<D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL, 1> featureLevels = { D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0 };
CComPtr<ID3D11Device> device;
D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevel;
CComPtr<ID3D11DeviceContext> immediateContext;
hr = D3D11CreateDevice(nullptr /* default adapter */,
    D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
    nullptr /* No software rasterizer */,
    createDeviceFlags,
    featureLevels.data(),
    UINT(featureLevels.size()),
    D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
    &device,
    &featureLevel,
    &immediateContext);
assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));

accelerator_view dxView = create_accelerator_view(device);
```

This is all taken from Chapter 11 of the [C++ AMP Book](http://www.gregcons.com/cppamp/).