# Accessing buffer using C++-AMP

Tags: c++, buffer, directx-11, c++-amp

Could somebody please help me understand exactly the step that is not working here?

I am trying to use C++-AMP to do parallel-for loops, however despite having no trouble or errors going through my process, I can't get my final data.

I want to pull out my data by means of mapping it

```
m_pDeviceContext->Map(pBuffer, 0, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, 0, &MappedResource);
{
    blah
}
```

But I've worked on this for days on end without even a single inch of progress.

Here is everything I do with C++-AMP:

Constructor: I initialise my variables because I have to

```
: m_AcceleratorView(concurrency::direct3d::create_accelerator_view(reinterpret_cast<IUnknown *>(_pDevice)))
, m_myArray(_uiNumElement, m_AcceleratorView)
```

I copy my initial data into the C++-AMP array

```
concurrency::copy(Data.begin(), m_myArray);
```

I do stuff to the data

```
concurrency::parallel_for_each(...) restrict(amp)
{
   blah
}
```

All of this seems fine, I run into no errors.

However the next step I want to do is pull the data from the buffer, which doesn't seem to work:

```
ID3D11Buffer* pBuffer = reinterpret_cast<ID3D11Buffer *>(concurrency::direct3d::get_buffer(m_myArray));
```

When I map this data (deviceContext->Map) the data inside is 0x00000000

What step am I forgetting that will allow me to read this data? Even when I try to set the CPU read/write access type I get an error, and I didn't even see any of my references do it that way either:

```
m_Accelerator.set_default_cpu_access_type(concurrency::access_type::access_type_read_write);
```

This creates an error to say "accelerator does not support zero copy"

Can anyone please help me and tell me why I can't read my buffer, and how to fix it?

Comment: I presume `m_myArray` is a concurrency::array and not array_view. Have you tried array_view? You can then call synchronize() which does the copy for you.

Comment: Have you tried running the code in release mode?  I was just having trouble the other day with my Intel HD graphics, it would always return all 0s with no errors if running in debug.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work for this. You should also check that the DX device you and the C++AMP accelerator are associated with the same hardware.

```
HRESULT hr = S_OK;
array<int, 1> arr(1024);
CComPtr<ID3D11Buffer> buffer;
IUnknown* unkBuf = get_buffer(arr);
hr = unkBuf->QueryInterface(__uuidof(ID3D11Buffer), reinterpret_cast<LPVOID*>(&buffer));
```

This question has an answer that shows you how to do the opposite.

[Reading Buffer Data using C++ AMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26448227/reading-buffer-data-using-c-amp?rq=1)